# Polymer - Are distributed Nodes Styled and then Distributed?

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, custom-element

Say I have two custom elements, defined as extensions of the Polymer Element:

- c-el1
- c-el2

templated like so:

#### c-el1

```
<dom-module id="c-el1">
    <template>
        <style>
            p{
               color:red;
             }
        </style>
        <c-el2>
            <p>custom text</p>
        </c-el2>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

#### c-el2

```
<dom-module id="c-el2">
    <template>
        <style>
            p::slotted(*){
               color:green;
             }
        </style>
       <p> <slot></slot></p>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

Should the `P` with *custom text* ,  be rendered `green` ? or `red`?

As of now, the custom element c-el1 styles the `P` with *custom text* which is **slotted** in c-el2

Answer (score 2):

`<p>` will be rendered red because the styles from `c-el1` are overriding the styles from `c-el2`

If you were not styling the `<p>` in `c-el1`, the correct way to select the slotted element in `c-el2` would be:

```
<dom-module id="custom-el2">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host ::slotted(p) {
        color: green;
      }
    </style>
    <slot></slot>
  </template>
  <script>
    class CustomEl2 extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'custom-el2'; }
    }
    window.customElements.define(CustomEl2.is, CustomEl2);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

More info on Polymer's `<slot>` here: [Styling Slotted Content](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/style-shadow-dom#style-slotted-content-distributed-children)

Comment: If I do not style the P in c-el1, **the slotted styles** apply with or without the `:host` selector.

Pondering if this overriding that occurs, is expected. cheers!

Comment: Correct, the slotted styles should apply in either situation if `c-el1` does not have a style for `p`. The overriding _should_ occur in the parent element because it gives you the ability to style the child elements without editing the source.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! `<slots>` in a polymer element, are **ONLY** rendering

- pre laid out,
- pre styled content

Just because the DOM  occupies the slot on a custom element, does not mean, that element gets to style it by priority.

We may have a `::slotted` rule on the element, but any parent element / page using the said slot on the custom element, gets the priority to style the DOM it lays in the said slot.

### Reference

[Eric's Post Here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom#stylinglightdom)

This ideally should be documented loud and clear on the [official documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/style-shadow-dom#style-slotted-content-distributed-children) on the site , under styling distributed nodes as a Note may be